# QR code not detecting in image BarcodeDetector

Tags: android, qr-code

I have implemented QR codes detection from an image using BarcodeDetector

```
 BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setBarcodeFormats(/*Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE|*/Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();
    if (detector.isOperational()) {
        Log.e("QR_READ", "Could not set up the detector!");


    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(pageBitmap).build();

    QRCodeList = detector.detect(frame);
}
```

Here QRCodeList is empty but that image has QR code in it.
but some images are working with code but some are not detecting but those images I checked in online, those were working in that.
why that code not detecting QR code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's only a problem with those QRCodes which you are scanning. Try to use an online QRCode generator and check if it works for each QRCode you'll generate.

In addition , you could print the raw value returned from scanning.
This is Kotlin but you can convert it to Java . Something like that:

```
val rawScanValue: String = QRCodeList.valueAt(0).rawValue
// or toast or whatever
Log.d('RAWVALUE',rawScanValue)
```

Comment: QRCodeList itself is empty .means it returning empty object

Comment: Yes and this may happen because the QRCode which he's scanning are not valid , not recognized.The same thing happened to me when I tried to test my app with QRCodes from Google Images and I realized that the problem wasn't from my code or from the library but from images.

Comment: i have test that image in this website , it giving results, https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/